# Install PHP8 in directory other than c:\php

Tags: php, windows, apache

I'm trying to install **PHP 8.2.1** on my Windows 11 machine to be used with Apache 2.4 installed as a Windows service and I don't want PHP on my `C:` drive. When I run `php.exe` from command prompt, I get errors about modules not being found.

```
C:\Windows\System32> e:
E:\> cd \app\php-8.2.8-TS
E:\app\php-8.2.8-TS> php -v
```

The output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: C:\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: C:\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd' (tried: C:\php\ext\gd (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_gd.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd' (tried: C:\php\ext\gd (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_gd.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: C:\php\ext\mbstring (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: C:\php\ext\mbstring (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: C:\php\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: C:\php\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2023 15:53:15) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

---

Is it possible that PHP has its path hardcoded in executable?

What else should be configured to have PHP in directory different than `c:\php`?

Current PHP directory is inside my PATH environment variable but it does not help:

```
E:\app\php-8.2.8-TS> set
```

The result:

```
Path=......;E:\app\php-8.2.8-TS
```

Comment: you simply need to configure php.ini in that folder

Comment: What folder? And what setting? I did set `doc_root = e:/www-root`, but it does not have anything with install location. What other setting should I configure?

Comment: **Folder**: Your installation path. **Setting**: the modules installation path (EXTENSION_DIR). You could also just adjust the paths one by one in the module part of your php.ini, but I would strongly advise you to just change your extension path. https://serverfault.com/questions/316156/change-php-modules-directory

Comment: @Wimanicesir Yea! <CRLF>
E:\app\php-8.2.8-TS>php -v  <CRLF>
PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2023 15:53:15) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64) <CRLF>
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies